# Show query results for keys not found [MySQL]

Tags: mysql

IF I am comparing 2 tables `users` `[user_id, username]` and `user_comments` `[user_id, comment]` where `user_id` are the keys in both tables. If I create a simple query to find the usernames for all users that made a comment. Is it possible if there is a user_id within user_comments that doesn't link to a `user_id` with `users` can we generate default response within the query where the unknown `user_id` is given a result of `anonymous`?

Basically I have 5 `user_id` 4 of which I can find in both `users` and `user_comments` however the last `user_id`. Can I create a query that will show the 5 results between the 2 columns however for the unknown `user_id` it gives a result of `unknown`?

Comment: yes u can .. just use the left or right join the the user id will return null.. set that as anonymous

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `left join`:

```
select coalesce(cast(uc.user_id as varchar(255)), 'unknown') as user_id,
       uc.comment
from user_comments uc left join
     users u
     on u.user_id = uc.user_id;
```

You do need to be careful about the type of `user_id`.  Assuming it is not a string, you need to cast it to be compatible with `'unknown'`.  Otherwise, `NULL` is a fine non-matching value.

Comment: I tired the right join and it works however I don't understand how I can change the `NULL` value of `user_id` into the value of `Unknown`

Comment: That is what the `coalesce()` does.